# How to use a Python stream object?

Tags: python, stream, io, python-2.7

I have a function that takes an opened file object `file` and writes data to it like so:

```
def Write(self, file):
    file.write("Data")
```

Now I would like to test that function and I thought it would be neat to do that with some kind of stream that is not writing data to a file. I could not find a Python2.7 class that does the job except the [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO) class. However, in Python2.7 this class expects a unicode string in the write function. `(file.write(u"Data"))` So I cannot test my `Write` function with the `StringIO` class.
In my workaround I created a little dummy class

```
class MyStream(object):
    S = property(lambda self: self._S)

    def __init__(self):
        self._S = ""

    def write(self, s):
        self._S += s
```

with which I can now successfully test my `Write` function.

My question:
Is there a native python class that does the same trick?
Thx in advance for any suggestions
Regards Woltan

Comment: There are two different `StringIO` classes in Python 2.7: `io.StringIO` and `StringIO.StringIO`.  The latter accepts both, `str` instances and `unicode` instances.

Comment: @Sven Great that does it. Post it as an answer and you will receive 15 points!!! ;)

Comment: The proper fix for this is to write unicode strings. You can convert from one to the other using `encode` and `decode`.

Comment: delnan's answer also mentions `StringIO.StringIO`, so simply accept that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of `io` states:

> Since this module has been designed primarily for Python 3.x, you have to be aware that all uses of “bytes” in this document refer to the str type (of which bytes is an alias), and all uses of “text” refer to the unicode type. Furthermore, those two types are not interchangeable in the io APIs.

I.e. if you use the backported Python 3 IO library, you have to use unicode. However, the original `StringIO` class - which considers bytes (Python 2 strings) text and accepts them - still exists in Python 2.7, it's just not in the backported `io`. Instead, it has its own module, also called `StringIO`.

Comment: Nope it does not work: `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: Saw this myself when testing. Edited with a wholly different suggestion inspired by a comment.